# cannot open Singular on a running emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, symbolic-computation, computer-algebra-systems

I am a newbies in Singular. I just downloaded Singular4-0-2_64.dmg, mounted the image, right-ckick, show the package contents, then moved the contents folder to the Applications directory. double-clicking Contents/MacOS/Singular (or Esingular) I have Singular running in a terminal (or via emacs in a terminal). But when I try M-x singular in a running emacs, it says "cannot open load file : no such file or directory, singular".

Then I copied .emacs-general and .emacs-singular to the home directory. Adding the following lines to .emacs

(setq load-path (cons "" load-path))
(autoload 'singular "singular"
  "Start Singular using default values." t)
(autoload 'singular-other "singular"
  "Ask for arguments and start Singular." t)

changing singular-emacs-home-directory into /Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs/ it still doesn't work.
Also when I replace .emacs with .emacs-singular, replacing the above directory, it gives the error:
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/Me/.emacs':

Symbol's value as variable is void: /Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs

Am I not finding the right singular-emacs-home-directroty or is there any other problem?

I appreciate your help.

Also I must mention that I am a user of emacs for Macaulay2. For that I have changed .emacs and .emacs-Macaulay2 in order to teach emacs where to look for M2. Is there anything similar to be done for Singular? Shall I have a file .emacs-singular somewhere?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Start by locating the file `singular.el` and place that inside your `load-path`, then restart Emacs.  From a brief glimpse at the manual -- https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/4-0-2/sing_23.htm -- it says there are more `elisp` files that will be needed.  So, perhaps consider copying them all over to your `load-path` to avoid repeated requests by Emacs for additional files.  Or, you could set the path to wherever it is that all the Singular `elisp` files are located.  That is your ticket -- find the directory where the `elisp` files for Singular are located.

Comment: I don't use Singular, but just downloaded the source code for version `singular-4.0.3.tar.gz` and peeked inside and found:  `cmd-cmpl.el`; `ex-cmpl.el`; `hlp-cmpl.el`; `lib-cmpl.el`; `singular.el`; `singular.xpm`.  Those all need to be in your load path, and the path to the xpm may need to be adjusted inside one or more of those `elisp` files.

Comment: Thanks. I located those files in /Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs directory. There are two more files in that dir: .emacs-singular and .emacs-general. I copy the content of .emacs-singular below this comment. It includes load path to all of those elisp files. But then-as you've mentioned- I should set the path to that directory. Could I ask how I can do that?

Comment: .emacs-singular content is here: [https://github.com/Singular/Sources/blob/ec3d9a4cd4ac241b8dec6377b20f0658bf3f1341/emacs/.emacs-singular]

Comment: By default, Emacs does not just read `.emacs-general` or `.emacs-singular` -- even if they are in the home directory.  Instead, Emacs reads things automatically in the home directory such as the `.emacs` file.  Check the value of `load-path` to see if it really contains the path to the `*.el` files you want to use.  The error you mentioned in the question -- "*cannot open load file : no such file or directory, singular*" -- is 99.99999999 percent probability that `singular.el` is not located in the `load-path`.  Type:  `M-x describe-variable RET load-path RET`  Consider using `.emacs` instead.

Comment: I actually copied .emacs-singular to the home dir and then renamed it to .emacs. It includes:
; load singular.el from `singular-emacs-home-directory'
(load-file (concat singular-emacs-home-directory "singular.el"))

; load .emacs-general from home or `singular-emacs-home-directory'
(if (file-exists-p "~/.emacs-general")
    (load-file "~/.emacs-general")
  (if (file-exists-p (concat singular-emacs-home-directory ".emacs-general"))
      (load-file (concat singular-emacs-home-directory ".emacs-general"))))

Comment: When I replace singular-emacs-home-directory with the directory that includes those elisp files, then I get the error: 
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/Me/.emacs':

Symbol's value as variable is void: /Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs

Comment: Btw, you are right, checking the value of load-path, it doesn't contain those elisp files.

Comment: So, open up your `/Users/Me/.emacs` and see where it is that you specified `/Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs` -- Emacs is tell you that is a **no no** :)

Comment: Here is the part of /Users/Me/.emacs that I've specified that directory:
; load singular.el from `/Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs'
(load-file (concat /Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs "singular.el"))

; load .emacs-general from home or `/Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs'
(if (file-exists-p "~/.emacs-general")
    (load-file "~/.emacs-general")
  (if (file-exists-p (concat /Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs ".emacs-general"))
      (load-file (concat /Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/sin

Comment: What about moving those lisp files to ~/.emacs.d/ directory? Does that change anything?

Comment: You need to double-quote the path and add a forward slash at the end -- because Emacs does not know it is a string -- Emacs thinks the path is something like BIRD or DOG or FISH, which have not yet been defined as variables.  `(load-file (concat "/Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs/" "singular.el"))`  **or** simply `(load-file "/Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs/singular.el")`  The `.emacs.d` is not technically in the `load-path` -- people usually add a sub-directory -- e.g., `/lisp` and then put stuff in there and add it to the `load-path`.

Comment: I double quoted the path and put a slash. Now I get the error:
Wrong type argument: symbolp, /Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs/

Comment: I checked other parts of the .emacs file and fixed other loaded paths and don't get anymore  that error when I run emacs. However, M-x singular does not start singular!!! Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some basic settings that assume the **Singular.app** has been installed to the `/Applications` folder.  I chose to set the absolute path to the executable, instead of setting the `PATH` in Emacs.  The `PATH` in Emacs on OSX is (by default) *not* the same as what one would generally except to see in let's say Terminal.app.  [But, setting the `PATH` is beyond the scope of this basic answer.]

My personal preference is to have all of the `lisp` and configuration files in a custom directory for purposes of editing and backup up.  This limited example just leaves everything where they are.

In the Emacs master branch (February 7, 2016), there is no built-in variable named `current-menubar` -- the configuration files are looking for the existence of that variable.  I did not spend the time to debug the built-in configuration files to find out what version of Emacs they were designed for, and I did not spend the time to make the Singular `elisp` libraries compatible with the latest Emacs master branch.

Add the following lines of code to the `.emacs` file in the home directory, save the file, and restart Emacs.  Then type `M-x singular RET`

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs/")
(require 'singular)
(setq singular-emacs-home-directory "/Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs/")
(defvar current-menubar nil)
(setq singular-executable-default "/Applications/Singular.app/Contents/MacOS/Singular")
(load-file "/Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs/.emacs-general")
(load-file "/Applications/Singular.app/Contents/share/singular/emacs/.emacs-singular")
```

Comment: I added the code to .emacs. Now [M-x singular] opens a new emacs window and also Singular running in terminal. But I want singular to be running in an emacs buffer. For that I changed the 5th line in the above code into [(setq singular-executable-default "/Applications/Singular.app/Contents/MacOS/ESingular")], but no success. Any idea?

Comment: I investigated just enough about this issue to ascertain how to load the built-in libraries, however, I did not dig into the code to find out what makes it tick.  I'm not even sure how it is supposed to work -- sorry.  Perhaps you could Google around for a tutorial with pictures to give you a better idea of what the `elisp` libraries are used for.  When investigating an error in Emacs, it is helpful to set `(setq debug-on-error t)` so that Emacs generates a more useful backtrace buffer.